# How do I wash stone stamped siding?

Tags: cleaning, exterior, stone, stucco, pressure-washer

I'm not sure what the actual name for this type of siding is, please let me know! It seems way too soft to pressure wash, and I've tried using a garden sprayer with 50% bleach on an area just to test with no effect.

- [Odd division of color](https://preview.redd.it/4m3z7u7bcsab1.jpg?width=4032&format=pjpg&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=3979af2f232c90c0bb11f4529bd8f32223cacf15)
- [Sills are darker and run down](https://preview.redd.it/2xutpmdecsab1.jpg?width=4032&format=pjpg&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=a8184c6399195cf8a4ff5f22fdd8bd790cb39a6b)
- [Algae throughout](https://preview.redd.it/u3qiykmhcsab1.jpg?width=4032&format=pjpg&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=42a85ff447cb5f0f6fd1b2079f0e79007141f5be)
- [Red (clay?) in some lower areas too](https://preview.redd.it/n4loml5kcsab1.jpg?width=4032&format=pjpg&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=0482e09f99577afbb06ab226c1efdbff92ec3f10)

There are lots of areas that need touched up and I'd love to avoid having to repaint the whole house to get it to a uniform color... but I'm feeling like I might have to.

Comment: No idea what that is - stucco with faux-stone markings, perhaps?